# how to go from a System.out.format print to consul to printing to a txt file

Tags: text, printing, format, output, out

I apologize I am a bit new to java and an having trouble figuring out how to print some formatted text to a file. I currently have the following printing as I wish to the consul.

```
System.out.format("%s%46f%40f%40f%40f%n", "Bubble Sort", bL1, bL2, bL3, bAvg);
```

Here I have 1 string and 4 doubles, what is the best way to keep this formatting but print to a file rather than the consul?